# How to change/reset the password of sitecore user programmatically

Tags: sitecore

I am using this code to change the password of user. But its not working

```
MembershipUser scUser = Membership.GetUser(userName);
if(scUser !=null)
scUser.ChangePassword(scUser.GetPassword(), user.Password);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this will work: `scUser.ChangePassword(scUser.GetPassword(), user.Password);` because you can't just get the old password.

Use the reset functionality instead:

```
string oldPassword = scUser.ResetPassword();
scUser.ChangePassword(oldPassword, user.password);
```

You can choose between reset (by not using the optional `ChangePassword`) or a change immediately after the reset.